# Desktop in Ubuntu 18.04 "too big"

Tags: 18.04, .desktop

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 in my new lenovo t480s and for some reasons, everything (from the dock up to the frames of the windows) are too big.

Just to be clear, they are not abnormal but they are significantly big. I tried Ubuntu 18.04 in a different laptop, and I didn't have these issues.

I have been looking online but so far, I haven't found any answer.

**UPDATE:**

I found, after some digging that apparently I am not the only one with these issues:
"The specs I got were:

- WQHD panel
- 16GB RAM (kinda regret not going for the full 24)
- i5-8350U (actually cost more than the i7 but I thought might run a bit cooler)
- 512GB SSD
- NFC
- WWAN

Installing Ubuntu 18.04 (alongside Win 10) went fine. Now for the issues:
Perhaps naïvely, I thought that scaling on a WQHD screen would not be an issue by now. I went for the high resolution screen since I love to have lots of space (and also prefer matte.) However, by default, Ubuntu 18.04 (with Xorg) does not support fractional scaling, so you're stuck with 100% (way too small, even for me) or 200% (too big, no screen space.) The non-default Wayland display server does support fractional scaling, and I find 150% to be a pretty perfect balance of size and space. The main drawbacks, aside from potential Wayland app-incompatibilities (which I haven't run into yet) is the ugly, blurry fonts on Gnome Shell, which still seems to have some fractional scaling issues. Fonts elsewhere look fine though, so I think I can live with this."

Because I have no experience, can somebody tell me what this Wayland app is?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible your scaling is set too large or your resolution is too low.
You can change these by navigating to the settings menu > Devices > Screen Display

[image: Settings menu]

The T480 I think, has a resolution of 2560 x 1440 so it should be set to that. If it isn't, then you may need to install additional graphics drivers. This resolution can considered a high DPI display, so the standard scaling of 100% might appear too small (and 200% may be too big).

The normal settings menu will only let you choose between 100% and 200%, however if install the [Gnome Tweaks](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tweaks) tool from the Ubuntu Software application, within it navigate to Fonts > Scaling Factor, then you can adjust that setting too, which might help.
[image]

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Yes I have already tried these and actually the resolution of the laptop is 2560x1440 , the scale by default set to 200%. I changed it to 100% but then everything is very small. There are no "special drivers" to install. At least it doesn't find any (plus the laptop doesn't bear any Nvdia or similar GC). So far I just used the scaling to make things somewhat better...

Comment: try setting your monitor resolution a little lower

Comment: Hey I tried it but it doesn't produce the desired result. The laptop has "WQHD IPS matt (2560 x1440)". Is it possible that this creates an issue? any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: I've been looking around but I haven't found any way to set the scaling between 100% and 200% :( you can run `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.xsettings overrides "[{'Gdk/WindowScalingFactor', <1>}]"`, change the 1 to 2, 3, 4 etc to increase the scale but you cannot do 1.5, 2.5 etc.

Comment: Yeah I know but it doesn't help either

Comment: My laptop has pretty similar specs, for me the best setup is: scale-100% and Font-Scaling-Factor to 1.3, in kitty Terminal I changed the font size from 11 to 13, this setup makes my eyes happy

Answer (score 0):

Frustrated as well with a FHD Dell XPS 13. Small screen can't handle 200% and 100% just a tad too small for my mid fifties eyes even with readers. It wears them out to spend too much time on some sites with small fonts. Yeah I use browser zoom but that's another step I have to keep doing. I did try the fractional beta in Wayland and it sort of works, but some stuff look like I changed my resolution to a non native setting. Just a lot of fuzziness. If my eyes were better I would stick with 100% scale raise the fonts a bit and not worry about scaling. Probably would be great on a 15.6" screen, just not a 13.3" one.